# How to direct multiple clean URL paths to a single page?

Tags: clean-urls

(Hi! This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow after years of finding answers here... Thanks!)

I have a dynamic page, and I'd like to have fixed URLs that point to different states of that page. So, for example: "www.mypage.co"(/index.php) is the base page, and it rearranges its content based on user choices. I'd then like to be able to point to "www.mypage.co/contentA" or "www.mypage.co/contentB" in order to automatically load base the page at "www.mypage.co" with the desired content.

At heart the problem is an aesthetic one. I know I could simply write www.mypage.co/index.html?state=contentA to reach the desired end, but I want to keep the URL simple and readable (ie, clean). I also, due to limitations in my hosting relationship, would most appreciate a solution that is server-independent (across LAM[PHP] stacks, at least), if possible.

Also, if I just have incorrect assumptions about how to implement clean URLs, I'd appreciate direction to a good, comprehensive explanation. I can't seem to find one...

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache, you can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). I have a rule like this where multiple restful urls all go to the same page, using regex and moving parts of the old url into parameters for the new url:

```
RewriteRule ^/testapp/(name|number|rn|sid|unii|inchikey|formula)(/(startswith))?/?(.*) /testapp/ProxyServlet?objectHandle=Search&actionHandle=drillIn&searchtype=$1&searchterm=$4&startswith=$3 [NC,PT]
```

That particular regex accepts urls like

- testapp/name
- testapp/name/zuchini
- testapp/name/startswith/zuchini

and forwards them to the same page.

I also use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) for Tomcat, but as you mentioned PHP, that doesn't seem that it would be useful.

Comment: This is good, but I'm not sure that I can add/remove modules to my server implementation. If they've compiled with mod_rewrite and the security rules allow me to write directives into my .htaccess this may work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a htaccess file to redirect all requests to one location and then from there determine what you want to return to the client.  Look over the [htaccess/dispatch system](https://github.com/peej/tonic/tree/master/web) that [Tonic](https://github.com/peej/tonic/) uses.